# Strange gap between keyboard and textbox when application bar is enabled

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a page with a textbox at the bottom, tap on it and the keyboard shows up. Everything is fine until I add application bar to the page: an annoying gap between keyboard and the text box came out of nowhere. Could someone tell me how to get rid of that? Thanks a lot.

[image: screenshots comparison]

Comment: Does this happen on a device as well? (Would rule out an emulator bug)

Comment: Yes. (I use emulator just to get screenshots easier.)

Comment: Have you changed the inputscope of the textboxes? As a test, try setting the inputscope to `TelephoneNumber` to see if it comes up as it seems to be the bar that's shown when spelling suggestions are shown.

Comment: No, that's not suggestion panel. 1) Spelling suggestions' background is the same color as keyboard (dark grey). 2) That gap only appears when application bar is enabled. 3) I've shown the comparison side by side, there's no reason why the suggestion panel only appears for one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set the rootframe transform when the textbox got focus.

```
var rootFrame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
rootFrame.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform() { TranslateY = -409};
```

and reset the renderTransform when the textbox lost focus.

The value of TranslateY is the height of the keyboard.

Seems like a system bug.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also set appBar.IsVisible = false; in situations like these...